# Attempting to scrape the roster number for all players on a football team but only getting the first one?

Tags: python, selenium

The website I'm attempting to scrape from is:

https://rolltide.com/roster.aspx?roster=226&path=football

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
numbers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sidearm-roster-player-jersey-number')
print(numbers.text)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If I change `elements` to `element` I am able to scrape the first player's number, but I encounter this error when I use `elements`. What do I need to change so that I can collect all these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
numbers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sidearm-roster-player-jersey-number')
for number in numbers:
    print(number.text)
```

Comment: That worked! Very odd, I had tried (what I thought) was that exact code yesterday and it didn't work for me. At any rate, thank you!